# Does it matter where we take our constant of integration?

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus

My equation is something like this after integration :

$$e^{4x}=4t/2 + c$$

But what if I take $c$ on the LHS?
$$e^{4x} + c = 4t/2$$

It looks like it won't make a difference but when I will apply boundary conditions for $t$ and $x$, the answer varies a lot.
Where do we take constant of integration in general ?

Comment: Do you have a function of $x$ and $t$? What did you integrate? When you have $a,b,a<b$ as boundary, like $\int_a^c f=\text{something },$ you don't add a constant in the end. Please, when you ask questions, write them down as if someone were asking you. Clear and precise.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, I would highly appreciate if you edit the post and write the full problem.

The two are different, say $C_1$ and $C_2$. Then we have
$$e^{4x}=2t+C_1\textrm{ and }e^{4x}+C_2=2t$$
Now, say the initial conditions are $(t,x)=(0,0)$, then we have
$$C_1=1-0=1$$
$$C_2=0-1=-1$$
Now, plug these back into your equations. Do you get different answers?